# Android Year Month and Time Zone

Tags: android, xml, json, latitude-longitude

The Xhanch API returns the data to you in JSON/XML format.

http://api.xhanch.com/islamic-get-prayer-time.php?lng=30&lat=30&yy=2013&mm=9&gmt=4

it require 3 parameters

1 year

2 month

3 gmt (4 or -4) return

I need help how i get these three parameter with efficent ways because iam making prayer base application

Comment: Use json, it will be easy to use than xml. Refer the links to know about json.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: I said how i get year month and gmt(+5,-5)...Iam not talking about xml or json parse

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get your params.

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 String yy = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "";
 String mm = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "";
 Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
 DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");
 String gmt = date.format(currentLocalTime);
```